# Adding multiple data-attributes in select options in JSP through Core/JSTL/Spring tags

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

JSP:

```
 <form:select path="owner" id="funding-owner" class="funding-owner">
    <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="obj">
        <form:option value="${obj.value}" data-street="${obj.street}"> ${obj.title} </form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

HTML output:

```
<select id="funding-owner" class="funding-owner">                        
    <option value="-1" data-street="100 First st">Waqas Ahmed</option>
    <option value="0" data-street="5881 Spring Rock Circle">Abdul Kareem</option>
</select>
```

Problem:
I want to add multiple `data-*` attributes in the select option instead of just one attribute.

```
 <select id="funding-owner" class="funding-owner">                       
    <option value="1" data-street="100 First st"  data-zip="44329" data-city="Columbus" data-state="OH">Waqas Ahmed</option>
    <option value="0" data-street="1000 NS Secon" data-zip="12345" data-city="Fairfield" data-state="NY">Abdul Kareem</option>
 </select>
```

How can I do that in JSP? (I can use Spring 3 tags)

Comment: any solution other than writing custom tag.

Comment: You can use just <option> tag inside foreach and provide any attributes you want

Comment: i did not get you. Could you give an example ? my concern is to load  multiple dynamic ATTRIBUTES inside <option>

Answer (score 1):

I have got working solution for it. In back end i used HashMap to store the key pair values. In JSP i pointed to key through reference of my base obj and it worked for me very well.

```
<form:select path="owner" id="funding-owner" class="funding-owner">
    <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="obj">
    <form:option value="${obj.value}" data-street="${obj.data.street}" data-city="${obj.data.city}" data-state="${obj.data.state}" data-zipcode="${obj.data.zipCode}"> ${obj.title} </form:option>
</c:forEach>
```

```
data-street="${obj.data.street}"
```

**data** = getter/setter of my HashMap

**street** = key in my HashMap (EL will print corresponding value)

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="owner" id="funding-owner" class="funding-owner">
    <c:forEach items="${itemList}" var="obj">
        <option value="${obj.value}" data-street="${obj.street}"> ${obj.title} </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but its not the solution, you are repeating my question. I have got solution let me share it here.